# Scroll-snap to table header with column span

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

Trying to build a table with horizontal scrolling and snapping to the yellow header columns which span over multiple columns. They should snap to the end of the red column, but always snap to the beginning of the table. What am I missing?

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
  width: 200px;
  /* to force scroll */
}

table {}

table thead .group {
  background: yellow;
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

table thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table tbody th {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

table tbody td,
table tbody th {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th/>
        <th colspan="4" class="group">
          Group 1
        </th>

        <th colspan="4" class="group">
          Group 2
        </th>

        <th colspan="4" class="group">
          Group 3
        </th>

        <th colspan="4" class="group">
          Group 4
        </th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th/>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>

        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>

        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>

        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Sticky</th>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>

        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>

        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>

        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The specs don’t provide the capability you are looking for. They only provide the ability to snap elements to a **containing element** (scroll container); either:

1. the start (left) of your chosen element (.group) to the start (left) of its scroll container,
2. the centre of your chosen element (.group) to the centre of its scroll container, or
3. the end (right) of your chosen element (.group) to the end (right) of its scroll container.

You are wanting to snap `<th>` elements relative to their first (sticky) sibling, another `<th>`. I’m afraid you're out of luck, at least with building something like this using HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: Not sure if this is true though, because I can do this vertically, right? In that case the tbody row snaps to the thead END... so there must be a way? I think I have my scroll-snaps wrong or something.

Comment: If there is indeed no way to do this, a dirty workaround could be to have two tables, one with the th cols and the other with the content and set an overflow for the second one, so the .group cols snaps to the start (which will be the end of the first table). But thats really dirty and will mess with screenreaders, etc.

Comment: @rx2347 would probably be possible with a little js